# How to inherit structure in a plain C

Tags: c, inheritance, data-structures

I am working in a plain C (embedded project, little memory) and I have a structure

```
typedef struct 
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
   float angle;
   float angle1;
   float angle2;
} Kind1;
```

There are cases when I need all fields, and there are cases when I need x, y and angle only.

In C++ I would create a base class with these 3 fields, would inherit from it another class with additional 3 fields and would instantiate one or another per need. How can I emulate this behaviour in plain C?

I know that I can make something like

```
typedef struct 
{
   int x;
   int y;
   float angle;
} Kind1;

typedef struct
{ 
   Kind1 basedata;
   int z;
   float angle2;
   float angle3;
}  Kind2;
```

but then I cannot pass pointer to Kind2 where a pointer to Kind1 is requested.

I know that it is possible to typecast and offset the pointer, I just wonder if there is a better, safer way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10872130/905902, including the syntax errors.

Comment: @wildplasser: It's weird that I missed this one, I tried to search SO first. BTW, syntax errors  - what do you mean? It's kind of a pseudocode, obviously.

Comment: It is tagged "C", so it should *not* be pseudo code. WRT syntax-errors: 1) the struct definition should be terminated by a ';' 2) a struct tag {Kind1,Kind2} does *not* introduce a typedef in C. (in pseudo code it could do anything, obviously)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that it is possible to typecast and offset the pointer

Not necessarily:

```
void foo(Kind1*);
struct Kind2
{ 
   Kind1 basedata;
   int z;
   float angle2;
   float angle3;
}

//...
Kind2 k;
foo(&(k.basedata));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it much like you would in C++:

```
struct Kind1
{
   int x;
   int y;
   float angle;
}

struct Kind2
{ 
   int z;
   float angle2;
   float angle3;
}

struct Kind
{
    Kind1 k1;
    Kind2 k2;
}
```

Comment: The project is intended for embedded devices, the whole point was to save memory, otherwise I can just live with Kind2 always.

Comment: @Flot2011: sounds like premature optimisation, but you can just use Kind1, Kind2 or Kind as appropriate for any given use case.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in plain C, the language has no such features. However, you could simplify the typecasts and offsets with pre-processor macros.

Answer (score 2):

Examples below assume these definitions.

```
struct base { char c; } *a_base;
struct sub  { struct base b; int i; } *a_sub;
```

---

Your "example" is in fact the (simplest) proper solution.

> but then I cannot pass pointer to Kind2 where a pointer to Kind1 is requested.

Yes you can.  The following is from the C11 standard but previous revisions had the same guarantees[citation needed].

> ## n1570 6.7.1.1.15
>
> ... A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Therefore `(struct base*)a_sub == &a_sub->b` and `((struct base*)a_sub)->c == a_sub->b.c`

So as long as your "super-struct" is the first member of your "sub-struct" you can treat one as the other **when accessing by reference**.  Basically don't do this.

```
void copy(struct base *from, struct base *to)
{
    *to = *from; // Oops, you just lost half your object.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of limited memory, preserve sanity by declaring two different structs:

```
struct Kind1
{
   int x;
   int y;
   float angle;
}

struct Kind2
{ 
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
   float angle;
   float angle2;
   float angle3;
}
```

I once had to work code which used a union and preprocessor `#define`s to make the code *look* more readable.  However, this quickly leads to madness.  If the two structures are actually handled as a subclass, then rearranging the fields is the least evil:

```
struct Kind1
{
   int x;
   int y;
   float angle;
}

struct Kind2
{ 
   int x;
   int y;
   float angle;
   // extended data:
   int z;
   float angle2;
   float angle3;
}
```

as long as they are carefully used with casting.  If anything goes wrong though, there really ought to be debug version namechecking to prove it all is done correctly.

```
struct Kind1
{
   char variant[6];  // initialized to "kind1" 
   int x;
   int y;
   float angle;
}

struct Kind2
{ 
   char variant[6];  // initialized to "kind2" 
   int x;
   int y;
   float angle;
   // extended data:
   int z;
   float angle2;
   float angle3;
}

function_expecting_kind2 (struct kind2 *p)
{
     if (strcmp (p->variant, "kind2"))
           error ("function expecting kind2 got '%s' instead", p->variant);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that I can think of which will save not more than 2*sizeof(float) bytes.

```
struct Kind2
{ 
   int z;
   float angle2;
   float angle3;
}

struct Kind1
{
   int x;
   int y;
   float angle;
   struct Kind2 *k2;
}
```

here the whole saving will be based on how much memory the pointer eats.

Init the pointer only if it is needed.